# Entity Framework 6, validation not working as intended

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a following piece of code

```
 var newPost = new Post()
                {
                    Activity = new Activity { Type = 1, ActivityTotalStatistic = new ActivityTotalStatistic() },
                    CreatedDate = oldPost.DateTimeCreated,
                    CategoryId = categoryId,
                    Title = oldPost.Name,
                    OwnerId = oldPost.UserID,
                    Slug = oldPost.Name,
                    LastUpdateDate = oldPost.DateTimeCreated,
                    PublishDate = oldPost.DateTimeCreated,
                    PostStatistic = new PostStatistic(),
                    PostItems = new List<PostItem>
                        {
                                new PostItem
                                {
                                    Activity = new Activity { Type = 2},<-- note this line of code
                                    CreatedDate = oldPost.DateTimeCreated,
                                    Title = oldPost.Name,
                                    Type = 1,
                                    Content = oldPost.Path
                                }
                            }

                    };

newDb.Posts.Add(newPost);
newDb.SaveChanges();
```

This is SQL schema for activity and statistics table

```
create table ActivityTotalStatistics
(
    Id int primary key identity(1,1),
    NumberOfLikes int not null,
    NumberOfDislikes int not null,
    SumOfLikes int not null,
    CommentCount int not null
)

create table Activities
(
    Id int identity (1,1) primary key,
    Type int not null,
    ActivityTotalStatisticId int not null  
        foreign key references ActivityTotalStatistics(Id)
)
```

As you can see, each activity should have activity statistic, because foreign key is not nullable, and my code should break, because Activity within post item does not have activity statistic instantiated.

But EF does not recognize it. What happens is that post item receives same activity statistic from this line of code

```
Activity = new Activity { Type = 1, ActivityTotalStatistic = new ActivityTotalStatistic() },
```

Is this a valid behavior of Entity Framework?

**UPDATE**
Activity.cs model

```
public partial class Activity
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Activity()
        {
            this.ActivityLikes = new HashSet<ActivityLike>();
            this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
            this.PostItems = new HashSet<PostItem>();
            this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public int ActivityTotalStatisticId { get; set; }

        public virtual ActivityTotalStatistic ActivityTotalStatistic { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ActivityLike> ActivityLikes { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PostItem> PostItems { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

ActivityTotalStatistic.cs

```
public partial class ActivityTotalStatistic
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ActivityTotalStatistic()
        {
            this.Activities = new HashSet<Activity>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfLikes { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfDislikes { get; set; }
        public int SumOfLikes { get; set; }
        public int CommentCount { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you post EF Model related with your table and Entity configuration related with your model?

Comment: @simonare do you want XML or designer screensthot?

Comment: @Robert Add your model class to the question.

Comment: @TanvirAjel i've added. it's database first

Comment: Can you share the Post and PostItem classes as well? What is the logical hierarchy of your entities? Does Post own Activity or Activity own Posts? I thought Post should own an Activity but the collection of Posts and PostItems in Activity confused me. Does Activity belong to a user or to a Post or something else?

Comment: @neptune Activity is like a base table. Post has its activity, post item has it's own activity. This way, i can reuse Comments table for ActivityComments, rather than having two tables PostComments and PostItemComments

Comment: @Robert are you sure the ActivityTotalStatistic that gets added to PostItem is the one from the Post and not a new one? I suspect EF is creating a new blank AcitivityTotalStatistic for you. Can you share what ends up in the database after you execute the code you shared?

Comment: @neptune it adds one activity, sets same activity id to post and postitem. If I do not instantiate the one on the post, it throws exception

Comment: I think EF is assuming wrong relationship directions. It might be treating Activity as a parent and both Post and PostItem as children of it. I know it doesn't explain why Activity gets reused in both Post and PostItem you are creating but I think EF usually doesn't expect specifying relationships this way.
See here on the section of Conventions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#conventions
What does the Post and PostItem tables look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a valid behavior of Entity Framework?

I don't think so - unfortunately there is no official documentation/specification for these tracking behaviors, but looks like implementation specific side effect / defect (bug).

**Rationale:**

It happens **only** when the change tracker contains **single** `Added` principal entity with autogenerated PK, the dependent entity has both explicit reference navigation property and FK property, all with default values ('0' and `null`).

It does *not* happen if:

(1) There is second `Added` principal entity:

```
newDb.Set<ActivityTotalStatistic>().Add(new ActivityTotalStatistic());
```

`SaveChanges` throws `DbUpdateException`:

> Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Activity_ActivityTotalStatistic' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

Not very user friendly, but still exception.

(2) The dependent entity has no explicit FK property, but correctly configured required shadow FK property. `SaveChanges` throws:

> Entities in 'MyDbContext.Activities' participate in the 'Activity_ActivityTotalStatistic' relationship. 0 related 'Activity_ActivityTotalStatistic_Target' were found. 1 'Activity_ActivityTotalStatistic_Target' is expected.

Again not very user friendly, but still exception.

(3) The reference navigation property has `[Required]` attribute applied:

```
[Required]
public virtual ActivityTotalStatistic ActivityTotalStatistic { get; set; }
```

`SaveChanges` throws `ValidationException` containing `ValidationError` with (finally) user friendly message:

> The ActivityTotalStatistic field is required.

---

Back to the original case. Only and only in that specific case, EF finds the single pending `Added` principal entity instance and associates it with all pending dependent entities having `ActivityTotalStatistic == null` and `ActivityTotalStatisticId == 0`.

All this for me indicates bug / unintended EF6 behavior. The best way  of preventing it seems to be decorating the required reference navigation properties with `[Required`] attribute, but that is problematic in Database First (edmx) generated entity model like yours.

Comment: We'll call it a bug or undesired behavior then.